printfing float value using %d & viewing its binary buffer
I was writing a piece of C/C++ code on custom hardware, but it did not have the ability to print floats using %f, something due to its unsupport for uart ftdi.
So, I wrote code that prints a float value using %d and also its buffer memory by using pointers.
Code:
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   float a = 6.7;
   
   printf("float a = %f\n", a);
   
   unsigned int a_int = *(int*)&a;
   printf("intbufa = %d\n", a_int);
   
   printf("hex   a = 0x%x\n", a);
   
   printf("int   a = %d\n", a);
   
   int comp_1s = ~a_int;
   printf("comp_1s = %d\n", comp_1s);
   
   int comp_2s = ~a_int + 1;
   printf("comp_2s = %d\n", comp_2s);

}

The output looks like
float a = 6.700000
intbufa = 1087792742
hex   a = 0xc0000000
int   a = -1073741824
comp_1s = -1087792743
comp_2s = -1087792742

What I'm not understanding is the result of printing int a. I recall it has something to do with 2's complement.
Can anyone explain it?

Are you mixing C and C++ languages?  The C++ language has std::cout and overloaded functions; C doesn't.  I don't recommend mixing the two, as overloaded functions to a C linker are difficult to manage.  Please remove unused tags.

What are the warnings that your compiler issued?  Please turn up the warning level to maximum.

You should send your floating point as data through the UART:  Write_UART(&a, sizeof(a));

@Caliber X, Tip: when initializing float objects, avoid using double constants. float a = 6.7; --> float a = 6.7f;.

The output from printf("int   a = %d\n", a); is meaningless with regard to float and the encoding of float.
Since %d expects an int and a is a float, the behavior is not defined by the C standard. A common behavior in modern systems is for the float to be passed in a floating-point register but for the printf to take the value for %d from an integer register. The result of this is that the value printf prints has nothing to do with the float value or its encoding.
In fact, the value printed, −1073741824, is C000000016, so we can see it is not related to the floating-point encoding of 6.7, which is 40D6666616 in the format commonly used for float. It was just some other value left in a processor register, likely by the prior printf. The same is true of the hex   a value.
unsigned int a_int = *(int*)&a; is not a proper way to get the encoding of a float because it violates the C standard’s rules for aliasing types. You can get the encoding in a defined way using a union or memcpy, shown below.
You can print the encoding of a float in a way defined by the C standard by using a union:
union { float f; unsigned u; } x = {a};
printf("0x%08X\n", x.u);

or copying the bytes:
unsigned u;
memcpy(&u, &a, sizeof u);
printf("0x%08X\n", u);

or by printing the individual bytes:
printf("0x");
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof a; ++i)
    printf("%02x", ((unsigned char *) &a)[i]);
printf("\n");

The first two of these require that float and unsigned have the same size, which is common in current C implementations. They will usually print the bytes in the same order as humans write numbers, from most significant to least. (They will do this as long as float and unsigned have the same byte ordering.)
The last does not depend on the size of unsigned but prints the bytes in memory order, not necessarily from most significant to least.

unsigned int a_int = *(int*)&a; invokes undefined behaviour. It has to be done in different ways.
   float a = 6.7;
   int b;
   
   memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof(b));


What I'm not understanding is the printing of int a. I recall it has
something to do with 2's complement.  Can anyone explain it?

Yes, it is related to two's complement. If the binary representation does represent a negative number, then %d will print a negative number.
Basically, all numbers with the most significant bit set are negative when used as signed integers.
signed char ch = 0x80;

printf("%hhd\n", ch);

will print -128.

signed char ch = 0x81;printf("%hhd\n", ch); - will print -127
signed char ch = 0x82;printf("%hhd\n", ch); - will print -126

...

signed char ch = 0xff;printf("%hhd\n", ch); - will print -1


Re “Yes, it is related to two's compliment”: No, the int   a output has nothing to do with the two’s complement of the float value or its encoding.

@EricPostpischil when float binary representation is copied to int and printed as int, then two's complement matters.

The output OP asks about, that labeled int   a, was not produced by copying the float representation to int and printing it as int.

@EricPostpischil *(int *)&float_variable implies binary representation. Isn't it?

The statement unsigned int a_int = *(int*)&a; copies the bytes of a to a_int. The output labeled int   a comes from the statement printf("int   a = %d\n", a);. That statement does not pass a_int to printf. It passes a to printf. The resulting output has nothing to do with what is in a_int (because it was not passed) and nothing to do with what is in a (because it is passed in a different register than OP’s printf uses to get the int for %d). Read the code. And look at the value; −1073741824 is not the two’s complement for 1087792742.
